# In Notepad++ how can I execute a script (like using F5) but with every save (Ctrl + S)?

Tags: notepad++

I am doing something like this in my <kbd>F5</kbd> command (execute):

```
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe G:\my_python_script.py
```

I want to run this script everytime I save the file. When I save this command as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, Notepad++ does not run it, only saves my file.

Comment: So, instead of pressing [Ctrl]+[S], *then* [F5] and [Enter], you just want to press [Ctrl]+[S] to save and run?

Comment: Yes. (characters_needed_to_send)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the NppExec plugin, the following macro will do what you want:

```
npp_save
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe G:\my_python_script.py
```

This can be bound to any key combination, does not rely on any existing shortcuts, and will bring up a save dialog if necessary.

Comment: took some fiddling on my part, but indeed, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can save a macro that will do this.

First, change the file so you can save. Then `Start Macro`, `Ctrl+S`, Execute your script, `Stop Recording`, `Save recorded Macro`.

Now you can either save this macro as `Ctrl+S` plus something, or just `Ctrl+S`, the latter would require you to un-map `Ctrl+S`.

If you must have it as a global hook into `Ctrl+S` (as Save) I do not have an answer for you, as I do not believe this is allowed, though you can macro any combination of events you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, I need to have 15 reputation to vote up you. :(

Comment: It does not work, how should i execute script so it will be recorded?

Comment: I believe you can give it a shortcut and then run that shortcut, in this case I was using a Python Script Plugin found here: http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/

Comment: how to resolve `conflict found`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) to easily create macros. For your case, the following script will work:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
^s:: ;Ctrl+S
{
    Send, ^s{F5}
    WinWaitActive, Run...
    Send, {Enter}
    return
}
#IfWinActive
```

You may need to run the script as an administrator, since Notepad++ uses its own [keyboard hooks](https://superuser.com/questions/194277/why-is-notepadd-blocking-my-autohotkey-shortcuts).

---

**Download:** [http://ahk.igalvez.net/**Notepad++SaveRun.exe**, 784KB](http://ahk.igalvez.net/Notepad++SaveRun.exe)

Comment: Note that the recommended site to download AutoHotKey from is ahkscript.org so the donwload from ahk.igalvez.net seems to be from iglvzx's own domain which doesn't currently resolve (so the download doesn't even work).  AutoHotkey is an excellent option to have a solution with, but rather than share a script, iglvzx seems to have preferred providing a custom installer.

Comment: The script is there in the answer - you can compile it yourself.  I think he added the exe link for folks not using autohotkey.